# Where are these scss functions defined in the Bigcommerce Stencil stack?

Tags: zurb-foundation, bigcommerce

I'm looking through the source for a store using Bigcommerce's default Stencil theme. In an SCSS file I see functions being used, but I'm not sure where these functions are defined. For example:

```
# assets/scss/layouts/footer/_footer.scss

.footer {
    background-color: $footer-background;
    border-top: container("border");
    padding: spacing("double") 0;
}
```

I can't find where this `container` or `spacing` methods are coming from? Are these part of scss? Part of [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html)? Or maybe something Bigcommerce has defined in their [Citadel](https://github.com/bigcommerce-stencil/citadel) library?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "container" function in

```
<your_theme>/assets/jspm_packages/github/bigcommerce-stencil/citadel@2.4.3/dist/settings/global/container/_container.scss
```

And the spacing function in:

```
<your_theme>/assets/jspm_packages/github/bigcommerce-stencil/citadel@2.4.3/dist/settings/global/layout/_layout.scss
```